# How to make == and %in% perform the same

Tags: r

For example if I have

```
colors <- c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green")

shapes <- c("Square", "Circle", "Triangle", "Diamond", "Star", "Pentagon", "Oval")

(com <- expand.grid(color=colors, shape=shapes)) #data frame from all combinations

(com <- paste(com$color, com$shape))

(ovals <- paste("Oval", shapes))
```

How would I use `==` to return the same things as `mean(com %in% ovals)`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Different functions (`%in%` and `==`) exists for a reason.

Comment: This is a very unusual request. It's like asking for `5-3` to return the same thing as `5+3`. What are you ultimately hoping to accomplish? There may be better/safer ways to do that. Changing how basic R functions work may easily break existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` is elementwise operator.  It works when we have the same length for both the arguments on the lhs and rhs or if the rhs element is of `length` 1 (i.e. it recycles the element to the length of the lhs element).  The objects 'com' and 'ovals' are different in `length` and the 'ovals' is not of `length` 1.  So, we could loop over the elements of 'ovals', do the `==` and get the `mean`

```
mean(sapply(ovals, function(x) com == x))
```

Or without lambda function

```
mean(sapply(ovals, `==`, com))
```

---

We could also `Reduce` the logical `list` elements to a single vector

```
mean(Reduce(`|`, lapply(ovals, `==`, com)))
```